# Kohana 'equals' validator does not accept sha1 function?

Tags: php, kohana, sha1, validation

I am making a kohana validator for validating the changing of a password. I want to insert in the validator the check if the old password matches the one introduced by the user as being the old password. i put the rule like this:

```
     ->rule(sha1('old_password'), 'equals', array($this->password));
```

but... it doesn't seem to validate if the equality happends anyway.  How can that be?  (if I put withput sha1 it validates, throwing me the error that the old pass doesn't match the inserted one, but, of course, it compares clear text with sha1 encrypted one in this case.)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is `this->password` already hashed?  How do you have `old_password`?

Comment: yes this->password is the user pass stored in the db - already hashed. old_password is received through post as cleartext

Answer (score 3):

That isn't how you use validation rules. The first parameter is the field name, second the rule, and the third, any parameters to pass into the rule.

Comment: yes it is true. but in my case, is there any possibility to make such kind of validation that i want? to verify directly from the validator if the sha1('old_password') equals the value received by post ? thanks

Comment: maybe: `rule('array_key', 'matches', array(':validation', ':field', $this->password))`

You need to setup the existing password in an array, and run the validation on it, compared to the new value. It's not clear in your example which is which.